# Restoring an online DB2 backup with redirect fails to rollforward

Tags: database, db2

I'm trying to restore a DB2 database to a new server/location. Below are the commands used, which are ran individually on the command line:

```
create db MYDBNAME

restore db MYDBNAME from D:\ on C: dbpath on C: NEWLOGPATH 'C:\DB2\NODE0000\MYDBNAME\LOGS\' REDIRECT 

SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 9 USING (PATH 'TBSP32K0000')
SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 11 USING (PATH 'TBSP32K0001')
SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS FOR 13 USING (PATH 'TBSP32K0002')

SET STOGROUP PATHS FOR IBMSTOGROUP ON 'C:\'

restore db MYDBNAME continue

rollforward db MYDBNAME to end of logs and complete
```

Backup information:

```
        MEDIA HEADER REACHED:
    =====================
    Server Database Name           -- MYDBNAME
    Server Database Alias          -- MYDBNAME
    Client Database Alias          -- MYDBNAME
    Timestamp                      -- 20180430230002
    Database Partition Number      -- 0
    Instance                       -- CTGINST2
    Database Configuration Type    -- 0 (Non-shared data)
    Sequence Number                -- 1
    Database Member ID             -- 0
    Release ID                     -- 0x1000 (DB2 v10.5)
    AL version                     -- V:10 R:5 M:0 F:9 I:0 SB:0
    Database Seed                  -- 0x4F18E7E4
    DB Comment's Codepage (Volume) -- 0
    DB Comment (Volume)            --
    DB Comment's Codepage (System) -- 0
    DB Comment (System)            --
    Authentication Value           -- 255 (Not specified)
    Backup Mode                    -- 1 (Online)
    Includes Logs                  -- 1 (Yes)
    Compression                    -- 1 (Compressed)
    Backup Type                    -- 0 (Database-level)
    Backup Granularity             -- 0 (Non-incremental)
    Merged Backup Image            -- 0 (No)
    Status Flags                   -- 0x60
                                      LOGARCHMETH1 is set
                                      LOGARCHMETH2 is set
    System Catalogs in this image  -- 1 (Yes)
    Catalog Partition Number       -- 0
    DB Codeset                     -- UTF-8
    DB Territory                   -- GB
    LogID                          -- 1323886033
    LogPath                        -- X:\DBLOGS\NODE0000\LOGSTREAM0000\
    Backup Buffer Size             -- 4194304 (1024 4K pages)
    Number of Sessions             -- 1
    Platform                       -- 0x17 (NT-64)
```

When I run the final 'rollforward' command I get the following error:

```
SQL0752N  Connecting to a database is not permitted within a logical unit of work when the CONNECT type 1 setting is in use.  SQLSTATE=0A001
```

dbdiag.log shows:

```
Rollforward failed to connect to database. sqlcode -752.
```

After running 'list tablespaces show details' I saw that all of my tablespaces showed 'restore pending, storage may be defined'

When I run 'list utilities show detail' I get this result (which never moves)

```
ID                               = 1
Type                             = RESTORE
Database Name                    = MYDBNAME
Member Number                    = 0
Description                      = db
Start Time                       = 12/05/2018 14:33:15.516532
State                            = Executing
Invocation Type                  = User
Progress Monitoring:
      Completed Work             = 67112960 bytes
      Start Time                 = 12/05/2018 14:33:15.516546
```

---

Notes:

- DB2 version 10.5 (windows 2008R2)
- Backup located on the d:\ (root)
- DB2 installation on C:\DB2\NODE0000

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the exact result of the `restore ... continue` step.

I suspect that at least one tablespace or storage-group is not mentioned in your instructions, or otherwise there's some issue with the specified containers.

To check: ask Db2 to generate a restore script (to compare its contents to your command-lines).

e.g.:

`db2 -v restore db MYDBNAME from D:\  REDIRECT generate script %temp%\myrestore.txt`

In the resulting file (myrestore.txt), compare the 'set tablespace containers' and 'set stogroup paths' lines with your command-lines, to see if any tablespace/storage-group is not mentioned in your command-lines.

Adjust your instructions for any missing tablespaces or storage groups and retry. You can abort the failed restore, drop the database if necessary , before retrying.

If the database originated from a different hostname, verify the current hostname has sufficient freespace on C: to fit the both the restored database AND the transaction log files. It appears your original database had its logfiles on X: but you want the new database to store them on C:. Normally you want the active transaction-logs to be on a different device than the containers.

Usually there is additional information in the db2diag , so it's necessary to read all the messages in db2diag between the start of the RESTORE action and the eventual SQL0752N. Check all such messages.

Comment: one thing I noticed whilst looking at the full restore script is that it only generates the tablespace changes (set tablespace containers) for only 3 out of around 15 entries... is this normal? The biggest concern I have is that the tablespaces show 'restore pending storage not defined' even after I have run the script above

Answer (score 0):

Is your database really called MYDBNAME or are you using a generic name here? SQL0752N means that you are trying to connect to a different database while still connected to the first one, so my suspicion is that you have a typo in your script and you're not using the same database name in the two RESTORE commands.